# PHP SimpleHTMLDom scraping problem

Tags: php, screen-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to do a scrape with SimpleHTMLDom and seem to be running in to a problem.

My code is as follows :

```
$table = $html->find('table',0);
$theData = array();
foreach(($table->find('tr')) as $row) {

    $rowData = array();
    foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {

        $rowData[] = $cell->innertext;
    }

    $theData[] = $rowData;
}

function array_find($needle, array $haystack)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if (false !== stripos($needle, $value)) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }

$searchString = "hospitalist";
$position = array_find($searchString, $theData);
echo ($position);
```

Which yields the following error:

```
Warning: stripos() [function.stripos]: needle is not a string or an integer in C:\xampp\htdocs\main.php on line 85
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it says needle is not a string and should be

Answer (score 1):

You have the order of the actual parameters reversed in your call to stripos.  See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php.  Just reverse the order of the arguments and that error should be fixed.

Change:

```
if (false !== stripos($needle, $value)) {
```

to

```
if (false !== stripos($value, $needle)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php), you should be passing in the needle second, not first. Try this:

```
function array_find($needle, array $haystack)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if (false !== stripos($value, $needle)) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The message is referring to the function argument of `stripos` and not your variable named `$needle`.

[`int stripos ( string $haystack , string $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

It is actually complaining about the *needle* `$value`